# opengl android time too fast

Tags: android, opengl-es, time

I'm trying to get the time using android and open gl for my racing game.

My code now is:

```
 deltaTime = (System.currentTimeMillis() + startTime) / 1000000000000.0f;
 startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
 tickTime += deltaTime;
 DecimalFormat dec = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
 Log.d("time", dec.format(tickTime/100));
```

but it's a bit too fast.

Comment: Didn't you mean `deltaTime = (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000000000000.0f;` with a minus instead of a plus?

Comment: with a minus i only get 0,1. I mean my code works, it starts at 0 and goes up but a little bit to fast, like 3/4 of a sec

Comment: @DonKanallie The delta times *should* be "relatively close to 0" and "about the same" (say in the range of 1-50 milliseconds). Also, I would recommend using milliseconds for delta time (as the precision will not be better) and they are "smaller" values: `deltaTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime` ..

Comment: (.. what does "goes up a little bit to fast" mean anyway?)

Comment: i just got it. this is based on the frames, so it's not constantly. i just noticed that in my update method i get the deltaTime from my framework. So its a very easy solution `time = time+deltaTime; DecimalFormat dec = new DecimalFormat("#.##"); Log.d("time", dec.format(time));` thanks for trying =)

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at a bit of Android Breakout:

http://code.google.com/p/android-breakout/source/browse/src/com/faddensoft/breakout/GameState.java#1001

The computation is similar, but note it uses `System.nanoTime()`, which uses the monotonic clock.  You don't want to use `System.currentTimeMillis()`, which uses the wall clock.  If the device is connected to a network, the wall clock can be updated, which can cause big jumps forward or backward.

The code also includes a (disabled) frame-rate-smoothing experiment that didn't seem to matter much.

As I think you discovered, the key to this approach is to recognize that the time interval between frames is not constant, and you need to update the game state based on how much time has actually elapsed, not a fixed notion of display update frequency.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're working in milliseconds, shouldn't you be dividing by 1000f instead of 1000000000000.0f?

Comment: i just got it. 
this is based on the frames, so it's not constantly.
i just noticed that in my update method i get the deltaTime from my framework. So its a very easy solution =)

       `time = time+deltaTime;
        DecimalFormat dec = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
        Log.d("time", dec.format(time));`

thanks everyone for trying =)

Comment: Oh ok :) What framework are you using? I'm currently trying LIBGDX and it gives you the deltaTime as well.

Comment: I'm using the 'Beggining Android App' Ebook from Techner Mario.

Comment: Yeah! That's the one I started using :) It's the base of the LIBGDX framework and basically explains how the framework is built. Really helpful. Good luck!